# An URI relativization in XQuery

Tags: xpath, xquery

How to relativize an URI to another URI?

uri1

```
file:/folder1/file2.txt
```

uri2

```
file:/folder1/folder2/file1.txt
```

needed result

```
relativize-method($uri1, $uri2) == '../file2.txt'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Something like this** (will rewrite it in XQuery):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:my="my:my">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    
 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:sequence select="my:RelativeUrl(url[1], url[2])"/>
 </xsl:template>
 
 <xsl:function name="my:RelativeUrl" as="xs:string">
  <xsl:param name="pUrl" as="xs:string"/>
  <xsl:param name="pBase" as="xs:string"/>
  
  <xsl:variable name="vurlSegments" select="tokenize($pUrl, '/')"/>
  <xsl:variable name="vbaseSegments" select="tokenize($pBase, '/')"/>
  
  <xsl:variable name="vCommonPrefixLength" select=
   "(for $i in 1 to count($vbaseSegments)
      return
        if($vbaseSegments[$i] ne $vurlSegments[$i])
          then $i -1
          else ()
     )[1]
   "/>
   
   <xsl:variable name="vUpSteps" select=
   "count($vbaseSegments) -$vCommonPrefixLength "/>
   
   <xsl:sequence select=
    "string-join
       (
               (
                (for $i in 1 to $vUpSteps
                    return
                      '..'
                  ),
                 (for $k in 1 to count($vurlSegments) - $vCommonPrefixLength 
                   return
                     $vurlSegments[$vCommonPrefixLength + $k]
                  )
                 ),
                  
                  '/'
        )
    "/>
 </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<t>
 <url>file:/folder1/file2.txt</url>
 <url>file:/folder1/folder2/file1.txt</url>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
../../file2.txt
```

---

**Update**:

Below is a pure XPath 3.0 solution:

```
let $pUrl := "file:/folder1/file2.txt",
    $pBase := "file:/folder1/folder2/folder3/file1.txt",
    $urlSegments := tokenize($pUrl, '/'),
    $baseSegments := tokenize($pBase, '/'),
    $idiff := (for $ind in 1 to max((count($urlSegments), count($baseSegments)))
                return $ind[$urlSegments[$ind] ne $baseSegments[$ind]]
             ) [1]
  return
   string-join(
                ((1 to count($baseSegments) - count($urlSegments)) ! '..',
                 $urlSegments[position() ge $idiff])
               , '/')
```

Comment: I think in the original solution, `$vUpSteps` should be: `<xsl:variable name="vUpSteps" select="count($vbaseSegments) -$vCommonPrefixLength - 1"/>`

Comment: @MartynasJusevičius I cannot decide what is correct and what not if we don't have any specifications what this function must do. The currently posted code correctly produces this result: `../../file2.txt` which I think is the correct. In the absence of any defining text to convince us that this is not so, what can we do? As for the XSLT solution, I would recommend to just use the XPath one - simply put it in an `<xsl:sequence>`

Comment: The ultimate defining text is the URI RFC. There are examples under [5.2.4.  Remove Dot Segments](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2.4).

Comment: @MartynasJusevičius The examples under "5.2.4. Remove Dot Segments" (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2.4) are only vaguely similar to the current problem. Most importantly, they deal with a **single** URI containing `.` and `,,` that is transformed to one that doesn't contain these navigation steps. It is my fault that sometimes I am trying to guess what an underspecified problem is, in order to help. (:

Comment: The problem with the `../../file2.txt` output from your functions that it does not resolve back to the original URI :) `resolve-uri('../../file2.txt', 'file:/folder1/folder2/file1.txt')` returns `file:///file2.txt` and not `file:/folder1/file2.txt`. `../file2.txt` resolves back to the original correctly.

Comment: @MartynasJusevičius The problem with this question is that it doesn't explain what is whole question is that it doesn't explain what is wanted and doesn't give enough examples to understand it. Thus, I offered what corresponds to my understanding of the question as currently formulated. Please, edit the question and improve it so that it would be more understandable,

Answer (score 2):

You could tokenize to get the directories, and then use a recursive function to compute the desired result. Something like the following (tested on try.zorba-xquery.com):

```
declare function local:compute-relative-uri($absolute as xs:string,
                                            $current as xs:string)
{
  local:compute-relative-uri-aux(tokenize($absolute, "/"),
                                 tokenize($current, "/"))
};

declare function local:compute-relative-uri-aux($absolute as xs:string*,
                                                $current as xs:string*)
{
  if (head($absolute) eq head($current))
  then
    local:compute-relative-uri-aux(tail($absolute), tail($current))
  else
    let $steps := (for $dir in 1 to count($current) - 1 return "..", $absolute)
    return string-join($steps, "/")
};

let $absolute := "file:/folder1/file2.txt"
let $current := "file:/folder1/folder2/file1.txt"
return
  local:compute-relative-uri($absolute, $current)
```

Comment: @user:284285  (@Ghislain Fourny) See my answer for a pure XPath 3.0 solution, which is non-recursive and has no conditionals (if-s)